# QPushButton focus

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a pushbutton which its background image gets changed regularly according to the packets ui receives from serial. When the user clicks the button, it becomes red with borders.

```
pb_Jack1Up  ->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border-image: url(:/ArrowKey/Up_Default.jpg);  } QPushButton:focus {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid; border-radius: 4px;}");
```

Now, what I want is to give the button some effects, to make the user understand that the button is clicked. like make the button go inside when clicked, and when user releases the button border shall no longer be set anymore. However, in my case the button border remains. I cannot also set style sheet with pressed and released slots, because the background image depends on what we receive from serial.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What about QPushButton:pressed instead focus?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
QPushButton          { ... }
QPushButton:disabled { ...  }
QPushButton:pressed  { ... }
QPushButton:focus    { ... }
QPushButton:hover    { ...   }
```

or take a look at [this](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2009/09/17/qt-stylesheets-button-bar-tutorial/) blog entry.

Answer (score 1):

The button keepsfocus after you release the mouse. Thats why it still has the red border.
You can check that if you activate another widget of the form, clicking, or tabbing, red border dissapears.

Try using

```
QPushButton:pressed
```

instead of focus